# How to create custom 2d matrix table in Matlab without for-loop?

Tags: matlab, time-complexity

I have a `M[12x2232]` matrix in matlab and three matrix `a[2232]`, `b[2232]`, `c[2232]`. I need to get a result matrix `ResultMatrix[26784x5]` where the total of rows 26784 is 2232*12 how you can see in the nested-loops below:

```
rowi = 1;
for ii = 1:2232
  for jj = 1:12
    row = { a(ii) M(ii,jj) b(ii) c(ii) jj*5 };
    ResultMatrix(counter, :) = row;
    rowi=rowi+1;
   end
end
```

But it get too time to execute (20 minutes). Is there a way to generate the matrix faster ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand well the description, but if your code works, you can do it like that:

```
new_a = repmat(a(:).',12,1);
new_b = repmat(b(:).',12,1);
new_c = repmat(c(:).',12,1);
new_M = M.';
ResultMatrix = [new_a(:) new_M(:) new_b(:) new_C(:) 5*repmat([1:12].',2232,1)];
```

Comment: and the solution is ok...?